# How to reference the MainActivity from an OnClickListener?

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-context

This is in the `MainActivity`:

```
    imgModeContrastLeft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               ImagePair imp = new ImagePair();
               String objId = "sMfSYvBxmX";
               imp.downloadImagePairInBackground(this, objId);
           }        
    });
```

But the `this` is not the `MainActivity`. How do I reference the main activity in the `OnClickListener`?

Comment: `getActivity()` or `getBaseActivity()` if I"m not mistaken. Nevermind I think it's `getBaseContext();`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do `MainActivity.this` to get the MainActivity context

Answer (score 2):

`v.getContext()` here is the "best" way

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    ImagePair imp = new ImagePair();
     String objId = "sMfSYvBxmX";
     imp.downloadImagePairInBackground(v.getContext(), objId);
 }
```

It will make it more "portable" so if you move, decide to reuse the code in another class, or change the class name, you don't need to change it.

The way you have it, `this` is referring to the inner-class and not the `Activity` `Context`

Comment: I think NameOfActivity.this is always better, even though the view can't be null

Comment: because you don't have to access the object to retrieve the same information

Comment: where did you get lost ?

Comment: @Blackbelt about 10 years ago but that's beside the point. I see what you mean but I'm not sure it will cause any performance or other issue

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Remember that a whole InnerClass is tied to every single object of the outside class, subject to the condition that InnerClass ain't static and you have created an object of InnerClass too.

Now, whenever you need access to the reference of the object that invoked the InnerClass the Syntax is:

```
OuterClassName.this;
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the right code:

```
imgModeContrastLeft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               ImagePair imp = new ImagePair();
               String objId = "sMfSYvBxmX";
               imp.downloadImagePairInBackground(MainActivity.this, objId);
           }        
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As has been noted in one of the other answers, you can qualify `this` with a class name to reference a specific outer class from within an inner class. However, this syntax is somewhat obscure, and so I would recommend the more explicit (if also more verbose) approach of simply assigning to a local:

```
 final MainActivity mainActivity = this;
 imgModeContrastLeft.setOnClickListener(...); // reference "mainActivity"
```